# Sql calcula data invés de inserir

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando inserir data no meu BD mas o sql calcula o resultado sempre é 1997
nos campos eu testei como "data" e não inseriu "varchar e text" me resultou um calculo de subtração da data atual

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'root');

   $query = 'INSERT INTO codes (code,dt) VALUES ('.$generator.','.$data_atual.')';

?>
```

Comment: @Francisco uma pergunta simples e esse alvoroço, se não quer ajudar não ajude simples !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta parênteses no sql. Não precisa usar pontos nas variáveis: se usar aspas simples nas variáveis, então use aspas duplas na linha SQL. PDO tem que preparar antes de executar.

```
$query = $conn -> prepare ("INSERT INTO codes (code,dt) VALUES ('$generator','$data_atual')");
$query -> execute();
```

Comment: Amigo, consegui aqui mesmo assim obrigado!! eu usei date('Y-m-d h:i:s');, data =NOW() e  no BD eu coloquei como timestamp